# I can't install any software Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation

[image]

Hello, I am trying to install the Tracktion T6 audio software (that now is free for Linux), I can download it on the website, but when I try to install it goes to Ubuntu Software and it doesn't install. It has already happened other times with another software, as Skype, every time I try to install it goes to Ubuntu Software and it appears a puzzle image and the name of the software, when I click in the button to install nothing really happens, I don't know what to do anymore, because I can't a way install through the terminal.

Comment: Try this `sudo apt install /path/to/name.deb`

Answer (score 0):

First install **GDebi** from Ubuntu Software, then right click on the package you downloaded from the internet and open with GDebi. Then click on the install button in GDebi.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to install it from the terminal with:

```
sudo apt install ./TracktionInstall_6_Linux_64Bit_latest.deb
```

This is done from the download directory where the package is, but do this if not in the download location:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/TracktionInstall_6_Linux_64Bit_latest.deb
```

To remove do:

```
sudo apt purge tracktion6
```

[image]